# resctructuring json from csv

Tags: arrays, json, lodash

I got a csv file that i manage to [convert to json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson), and i got this

```
[{
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_a',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_a',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_a',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_a_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_a',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_a',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_a',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_a_2'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_a',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_b',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_b',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_b_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_a',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_b',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_b',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_b_2'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_b',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_c',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_c',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_c_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_b',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_c',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_c',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_c_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_b',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_d',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_d',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_d_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#1',
  last_name: 'lastname#1',
  email: 'first@email.com',
  category: 'category_b',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_d',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_d',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_d_2'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_c',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_ab',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_ab',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_ab_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_c',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_ab',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_ab',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_ab_2'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_c',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_cd',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_cd',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_cd_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_c',
  level_of_experience: '1-2 years',
  type: 'media_type_cd',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_cd',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_cd_2'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_d',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_ef',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_ef',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_ef_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_d',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_ef',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_ef',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_ef_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_d',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_gh',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_gh',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_gh_1'
}, {
  first_name: 'account#2',
  last_name: 'lastname#2',
  email: 'second@email.com',
  category: 'category_d',
  level_of_experience: '3-5 years',
  type: 'media_type_gh',
  price: 'price_for_media_type_gh',
  work_sample: 'sample_for_media_type_gh_2'
}]
```

By doing combination of lodash map, groupby, and reduce, i manage to solve it down to this

```
[{
  "first_name": "account#1",
  "last_name": "lastname#1",
  "email": "first@email.com",
  "details": {
    "portfolio": {
      "category_data": {
        "category_a": {
          "portfolio_type_data": {
            "media_type_a": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_b": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_c": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_d": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "category_b": {
          "portfolio_type_data": {
            "media_type_a": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_b": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_c": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_d": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_a",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "first_name": "account#2",
  "last_name": "lastname#2",
  "email": "second@email.com",
  "details": {
    "portfolio": {
      "category_data": {
        "category_c": {
          "portfolio_type_data": {
            "media_type_ab": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_cd": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_ef": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_gh": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "category_d": {
          "portfolio_type_data": {
            "media_type_ab": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_cd": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_ef": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            },
            "media_type_gh": {
              "cost": "price_for_media_type_ab",
              "sample_file": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

while i want it to be like this

```
{  
  "first_name":"account#1",
  "last_name":"lastname#1",
  "details":{  
     "portfolio":{  
        "category_data":{
          ...
           "category_a":{         
              ...
              "portfolio_type_data":{  
                 "media_type_a":{  
                    "price":"price_for_media_type_a",
                    "sample_file":["sample_for_media_type_a_1", "sample_for_media_type_a_2"]
                 },
                 "media_type_b":{  
                    "price":"price_for_media_type_b",
                    "sample_file":["sample_for_media_type_b_1", "sample_for_media_type_b_2"]
                 }
              }
              ...
           },
           "category_b":{         
              ...
              "portfolio_type_data":{  
                 "media_type_c":{  
                    "price":"price_for_media_type_c",
                    "sample_file":["sample_for_media_type_c_1", "sample_for_media_type_c_2"]
                 },
                 "media_type_d":{  
                    "price":"price_for_media_type_d",
                    "sample_file":["sample_for_media_type_d_1", "sample_for_media_type_d_2"]
                 }
              }
              ...
           },
        }
     }
  }
}
```

And here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/littlechad/jd4z89gr/)

Comment: Holy moly man... To be any level of efficient, you don't want to loop over all of your data that many times.

Comment: @toastal i know, i got carried away, i know there must be some shorter way in doing this, havent figured out just yet though

Comment: You're not going to like it, but since the data structure is going from flat to nest, this probably needs to be built in all in one giant reduce with an empty object `{}`, accumulator. Loop and process the data once and bucket everything on that first go-around.

Comment: @toastal i get what you're trying to say. this is a legacy project i had to work on, we are actually initiating a major restructure about this whole thing, just need to take care some ad-hocs using the current data that we have, which is what you saw up there. Anyways, i think i got like 95% done now, will share here mostly just on the `how to reduce` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes sense to refactor and do it in one iteration (basically as @toastal suggested).
Here is how you can acheive this with some lodash magic.

```js
let reducedData = _.reduce(csvData, (memo, value) => {
 let userInfo = {
  first_name: value.first_name,
  last_name: value.last_name,
  email: value.email,
  level_of_experience: value.level_of_experience
 };

 //Search for user info, and push into memo if not found
 let user = _.find(memo, userInfo);

 if (!user) {
  memo.push(userInfo);
  user = userInfo;
 }

 //Same trick with portfolio type. Lodash allows to check nested path with _.get call
 const typePropertyPath = `details.portfolio.category_data.${value.category}.portfolio_type_data.${value.type}`;
 let typeData = _.get(user, typePropertyPath);

 if (typeData) {
  typeData.sample_file.push(value.work_sample);
 } else {
  //Set if not found (lodash takes care of nesting)
  _.set(user, typePropertyPath, {
   price: value.price,
   sample_file: [value.work_sample]
  });
 }

 return memo;
}, []);
```

Hope this helps.